# Formatting JButtons inside JPanels

Tags: java, formatting, chess

So, I'm making a chessboard, and whenever I try to put down the buttons, they keep reorienting and get more and more messy towards the bottom right. The first button in the top right (squareB[0][0]) looks fine, but all the other JButtons are messed up.

So my question is how do I fix this or allow me to place the button at certain coordinates?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;

public class Test implements ActionListener
{
private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
private JPanel[][] square = new JPanel[8][8];
private JButton[][] button = new JButton[8][8];
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Test();
}
Test() 
{
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,8));
    for(int x=0; x<8; x++)
    {
        for(int y=0; y<8; y++)
        {
            square[x][y] = new JPanel();
            frame.add(square[x][y]);
            square[x][y].setSize(100,100);
            square[x][y].setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
            if(y%2==0)
                if(x%2==0)
                    square[x][y].setBackground(Color.white);
                else
                    square[x][y].setBackground(Color.black);
            if(y%2!=0)
                if(x%2==0)
                    square[x][y].setBackground(Color.black);
                else
                    square[x][y].setBackground(Color.white);

            button[x][y] = new JButton();
            button[x][y] = new TestMethods(x,y);
            square[x][y].add(button[x][y]);
            button[x][y].setOpaque(false);
            button[x][y].setContentAreaFilled(true);  
            button[x][y].setBorderPainted(true);
            button[x][y].addActionListener(this);
        }
    }
    frame.setSize(800,800);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

}
}
class TestMethods extends JButton
{
private int x, y;
public TestMethods(int x, int y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
public int getX() {return x;}

public int getY() {return y;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think part of your problem is related to the `getX` and `getY` methods of your `TestMethods` class.  These are overriding methods used by the `JButton` to determine it's location on it's parent and you should avoid overriding them

```
class TestMethods extends JButton
{
    private int x, y;
    public TestMethods(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int getX() {return x;}

    public int getY() {return y;}
}
```

I would, instead, use method names that relate better to your purpose.

```
class TestMethods extends JButton
{
    private int gridX, gridY;
    public TestMethods(int x, int y)
    {
        this.gridX = x;
        this.gridY = y;
    }
    public int getGridX() {return gridX ;}

    public int getGridY() {return gridY ;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I cannot find what is going bad with your code, so I did write a method that does the same. I know this is not an answer, but may be useful:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));

    boolean isWhite = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            final JButton button = new JButton();
            if (isWhite) {
                button.setBackground(Color.white);
            } else {
                button.setBackground(Color.black);
            }
            isWhite = !isWhite;
            frame.add(button);
        }
        isWhite = !isWhite;
    }
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the answer given by MadProgrammer. Also I have modified your example to create the chessboard. Please look at the modified way of creating chessboard pattern.

```
Test() 
{
  frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,8));
  for(int x=0; x<8; x++)
  {
    for(int y=0; y<8; y++)
    {
        square[x][y] = new JPanel();
        frame.add(square[x][y]);
        square[x][y].setSize(100,100);
        square[x][y].setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));



        button[x][y] = new TestMethods(x,y);
        button[x][y].setOpaque(true);
        button[x][y].setContentAreaFilled(true);  
        button[x][y].setBorderPainted(true);
        button[x][y].addActionListener(this);

        if((y + x)%2==0)
        {
            button[x][y].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
        else
        {
            button[x][y].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        }

        square[x][y].add(button[x][y]);
    }
  }
  frame.setSize(800,800);
  frame.setVisible(true);
}
```